# MultiIndex pivot in pandas, long-to-wide problem

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have what I am sure is a simple long to wide problem, but I cannot get the syntax right on how to handle this when I have multiple columns at play.

My data looks like this:

```
>>> df.head()
        s_name   geo    zip  date value
0        A002X   zip  00601  2010     1
1        A002Y   zip  00601  2010     2
2        A003X   zip  00601  2010     3
3        A003Y   zip  00601  2010     4
...
.        A002X   zip  00602  2010     8
.        A002Y   zip  00602  2010     9
.        A003X   zip  00602  2010    10
.        A003Y   zip  00602  2010    11
```

I would like it to look like this, that is, the contents of the s_name column become new columns, and their values are the 'value' column, grouped by (geo,zip,date):

```
>>> df2.head()
         A002X A002Y A003X A003Y     geo    zip  date
0            1     2     3     4     zip  00601  2010
1            8     9    10    11     zip  00602  2010
2           19    20    21    22     zip  00603  2010
3           31    32    33    45     zip  00604  2010
```

I've tried a couple like this

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='s_name', values=["geo","zip","date","value"])

>>> df.pivot(columns='s_name', values=["geo","zip","date","value"]).unstack().reset_index()
```

I feel like I'm really close, but nothing seems to match up.  This, for example, drops the extra non-s_name values:

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='name', values=["value"]).head()
```

How do I get the format I'm looking for?

Comment: Does each group {'A002X', ....} have the same number of observations?

Comment: It ought to. (But data is data....)

Answer (score 3):

What I will do `pivot_table`

```
s=df.pivot_table(index=['geo','zip','date'],columns='s_name',values='value',aggfunc='sum')
s
s_name        A002X  A002Y  A003X  A003Y
geo zip date                            
zip 601 2010      1      2      3      4
    602 2010      8      9     10     11
#s=s.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to set the dimensions as indices, and unstack the dimension that is desired as columns

This leaves a multi-index in the final output

Example:

```
# with df as the following
  s_name  geo  zip  date  value
0  A002X  zip  601  2010      1
1  A002Y  zip  601  2010      2
2  A003X  zip  601  2010      3
3  A003Y  zip  601  2010      4

ids = df.columns[:-1].tolist()
df2 = df.set_index(ids).unstack(0)
df2
# outputs:
             value                  
s_name       A002X A002Y A003X A003Y
geo zip date                        
zip 601 2010     1     2     3     4
```

Then flatten the multiindex, keeping the 2nd level:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Comment: The flatten gives the error: `IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2` df or df2?

Comment: @Mittenchops I believe is df2.

Comment: @Mittenchops, that was a typo in the last line as pointed out by Daniel Mesejo. The typo has been corrected.